# How to insert data on SQL Server Database in VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

has anyone know how to insert some data on SQL Server database??
i've tried this code, but it not works for me..
here's the code:

```
    Dim constring As String = "Data source=.\sqlexpress;attachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=true;connect timeout=30;user instance=true"
    Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(constring)
    Dim query As SqlCommand

        Dim s As String

        connection.Open()

        s = "insert into login values(@un,@pass)"
        query = New SqlCommand(s, connection)
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", "111")
        query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", "222")

        query.ExecuteNonQuery()

        connection.Close()
```

Comment: How does it not work?  Do you get an error?  Wher does the error happen?  What is the state of the relevant objects at the time?

Comment: What's the problem here?  What's the error?

Comment: @David: it has no error, but the database is still empty..

Comment: @LarsTech: still can't insert the data on database and the database is still empty.. :(

Comment: When you debug into the code,mod these statements get executed?  Do they have the values you expect?  If you profile the database, does the query get executed?  If you copy the query from the profiler and execute it manually, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax to create a login is incorrect.  You are looking for:

```
CREATE LOGIN <loginName>
WITH PASSWORD = 'YourPassword'
```

More information about `Create Login` can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx)